# Can I withdraw Small Overcontribution from RRSP?

Tags: canada, tax-deduction, withdrawal, rrsp, excess-contribution

My contribution room for my RRSP is 23.5k, I accidentally contributed 25k though. I realize my over-contribution is within the 2k that CRA allows, but I would prefer to keep the extra $1,500 outside of my RRSP if possible as I won't be receiving a tax credit for it.

Am I able to just transfer this $1,500 out? Or will I have to pay tax on the $1,500 if I do this?

Alternatively, if I just leave the extra $1,500 can I claim it next year when my contribution room increases?

Answer (score 1):

Slight side-step to your first question to highlight your second:

"Alternatively, if I just leave the extra $1,500 can I claim it next year when my contribution room increases?"

Yes, you can do this, and I would say it is the recommended approach.

Technically, if you have no fear of miscalculating your RRSP amount, you can happily use the $2k 'buffer' as a way to allow a little bit more of your investment income to have tax deferred to retirement, even though you don't get the immediate deduction for it.